# SonarQube analysis fails with "org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar"

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube analysis running on a TeamCity build with Ant fails with "org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar". The excerpt from the build log from the TeamCity server is:

```
[11:46:01]E:     [Step 1/1] sonar (13s)
[11:46:01]E:         [sonar] sonar:sonar (13s)
[11:46:01] :             [sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
[11:46:01] :             [sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.3
[11:46:01] :             [sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/D:/project/tcity/agentWork/tcagentW3_Windows/work/f0604fb8834cecda/lib/dev/sonar-ant-task-2.3.jar
[11:46:01] :             [sonar:sonar] INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[11:46:01] :             [sonar:sonar] INFO: Work directory: D:\project\tcity\agentWork\tcagentW3_Windows\work\f0604fb8834cecda\.sonar
[11:46:01] :             [sonar:sonar] INFO: SonarQube Server 4.5.4
[11:46:03] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:03.025 INFO  - Load global referentials...
[11:46:04] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:04.312 INFO  - Load global referentials done: 1291 ms
[11:46:04] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:04.328 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\tcagentW3_Windows\.sonar\cache
[11:46:04] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:04.353 INFO  - Install plugins
[11:46:04] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:04.672 INFO  - Download sonar-css-plugin-1.2.jar
[11:46:04] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:04.867 INFO  - Download sonar-pmd-plugin-2.4.1.jar
[11:46:05] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:05.053 INFO  - Download sonar-android-plugin-1.1.jar
[11:46:05] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:05.446 INFO  - Download sonar-jmeter-plugin-0.3.jar
[11:46:05] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:05.773 INFO  - Download sonar-csharp-plugin-4.0.jar
[11:46:05] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:05.871 INFO  - Download sonar-java-plugin-3.3.jar
[11:46:06] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:06.149 INFO  - Download sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.3.jar
[11:46:06] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:06.334 INFO  - Download sonar-python-plugin-1.5.jar
[11:46:06] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:06.449 INFO  - Download sonar-javascript-plugin-2.6.jar
[11:46:06] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:06.542 INFO  - Download sonar-build-stability-plugin-1.3.jar
[11:46:06] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:06.580 INFO  - Download sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.2.jar
[11:46:06] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:06.780 INFO  - Download sonar-groovy-plugin-1.1.1.jar
[11:46:07] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:07.093 INFO  - Download sonar-php-plugin-2.5.jar
[11:46:09] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:09.098 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
[11:46:09] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:09.109 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sonar-so-1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=sonar-so-2)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SONARD)))
[11:46:11] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:11.669 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
[11:46:15] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:15.505 INFO  - Load project referentials...
[11:46:15] :             [sonar:sonar] 11:46:15.522 INFO  - Load project referentials done: 17 ms
[11:46:15]E:             [sonar:sonar] org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
[11:46:15]W:     [Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
[11:46:15]W:     [Step 1/1] Ant output
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:698)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:646)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:677)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:209)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:102)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output]   ... 24 more
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output] 
[11:46:15]W:         [Ant output] Total time: 21 minutes 42 seconds
[11:46:16]i:     [Step 1/1] ##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='buildStageDuration:buildStepRUNNER_Ant_244' value='1303420.0']
[11:46:16]E:     [Step 1/1] Step Ant failed
```

The message "Unable to execute Sonar" is not very explaining to me. Where is the problem?

Comment: This is strange, the stacktrace seems to be truncated. Could you please try to run the same command on your box to avoid possible console truncation by Teamcity?

Answer (score 0):

I Too run in to the same problem. Please check for the compatibility of the sonar-ant-task-*.jar version with the Sonarqube. I have updated jar to the sonar-ant-task-2.2 and it works for me.